# Unable to extract yielded value from python websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, client, yield

The [documentation](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-websockets.client) for python 3.x `Websockets` library says `Calling a python websockets.client.connect function yields a WebSocketClientProtocol which can then be used to send and receive messages.`

However, i'm unable to extract the `WebSocketClientProtocol` object with which i want to use the `recv()` function, defined in the parent of `WebSocketClientProtocol`.

I'm not very familiar with the python `yield`, how do i go about this?

Code snippet:

```
ws1 = websockets.client.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org')
print(ws1)
```

gives me the following output:

```
<websockets.py35.client.Connect object at 0x7f103c747e48>
```

Now, how do i get a `WebSocketClientProtocol` object from the `ws1`?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets to make question more explicit.

Comment: @Sraw done, comment has been added.